# Refreshing makes the user logged out in react, redux, nodejs and cookie based auth

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cookies, redux

```
router.post("/api/users/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findbyCreds(req.body.email, req.body.password);
    const token = await user.createToken();
    res.cookie("token", token, {
      // maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000,
      httpOnly: true,
      // secure: true,
      // sameSite: true,
    });
    res.send({ user, token });
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send(e);
  }
});
```

This is my login route on the server side (nodejs) and it work fine by making a cookie and passing it to the browser for all the further request's.

```
export const loginUser = (formValues) => async (dispatch) => {
  const user = await axios.post("/api/users/login", formValues);
  dispatch({
    type: "LOGIN_USER",
    payload: user.data,
  });
  history.push("/");
};
```

This is my redux action which calls the server forlogin request and it also works fine and it passes the user information to the redux state which i use further.

The problem is when i refresh my webpage redux state gets empty and the value stored in the user of redux sate goes null while i want it to ressist so that user should not login again & again after refreshes. Moreover my cookie is still there in browser after i refresh.

Comment: Before loading the component, can't you check if cookie is still valid then instead of asking user to login again, navigate him to the requested route?

Comment: on the refresh, redux data will be cleared. There is several npm packages are available for persisting redux data. ie., persist some of the app’s state to localStorage and restore it after a refresh. So you can try any of the package or try yourself to persist redux data, that will solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

there are external libraries like redux-persist, async-storage, which deals with re-hydrating the store during launch to handle page refreshes. But internally they all use the localStorage of browser to store and retrieve keys.

1. Create an initial state on the reducer with userAuthenticated flag set to false, and isAppLoaded flag to false.

   `let initialState ={ isAppLoaded :false, userAuthenticated :false}`
2. On componentDidMount of App.js file, look for the isAppLoaded flag value, and update userAuthenticated flag from localStorage.

   `componentDidMount=()=>{  if(!this.props.isAppLoaded) {                                                                           let token =localStorage.get('token');} //dispatch an action to update store for userAuthenticated and isAppLoaded }`